# Dispenser behavior in PS3 edition of Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I recently was able to get the dispensers in Minecraft PS3 edition to correctly place minecarts for the first time ever. I replicated the behavior around a dozen times,  but now the exact same setup is dropping carts as items.

What am I missing here?

Everything is placed exactly the same. Heck... I even loaded up my creative test world (the same exact setup I tested with originally) and isn't working.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that you're using droppers instead of dispensers, and somehow got them mixed up.  That theory doesn't really pan out, though, since you shouldn't have access to droppers just yet (it looks like it's coming soon to PS3 and PS4).

Comment: @MBraedely that was my fist thought... i have no idea how it worked, just that it did.

Comment: @MBraedley Minecraft PS3 doesn't have droppers

Comment: @TheIdiotGamer: Yeah, I know, I acknowledged that in my comment.